# having a small problem with a integration calculation

Tags: calculus

I am studying for the exam and found the following formula on my notebook:

$\displaystyle \int_{r+1}^\infty (x-(r+1))g(x)dx$

=$\displaystyle \int_{r}^\infty (x-r)g(x)dx$

But I believe that this is not generally true unless $g$ is special such as a peridoic function.

I suspect that the above function is probably supposed to be

$\displaystyle \int_{r+1}^\infty (x-(r+1))g(x)dx$

=$\displaystyle \int_{r}^\infty (x-r)g(x+1)dx$

Could anyone help me confirm that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second formula is correct in general. What you have in the first formula is wrong. You are correct.

Answer (score 1):

That is correct.  An easy spot check is that the integrand at the lower limit in both cases is $(0)(g(r+1))$ which the first one fails-it is $(0)(g(r+1))$ in the top and $(0)(g(r))$ in the second line.  More formally you could do a $u$ substitution of $u=x-1$ and notice that (up to the name of the dummy variable) they match.